# Using of \null command alone

Tags: code

I'm trying to understand what is the purpose of \null command. To do this I wrote the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}

Ciao ciao \null \null \null \null ciao
ciao

\end{document}
```

but it seems to do nothing. When is it used alone?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello @PhelypeOleinik, in the answer that you indicate there is not an explanation of \null, but a tautology, and there are not examples in which there is only \null. In my question I edit the answer adding "alone".

Comment: `\null` does an `\hbox{}`, which kind of "anchors" some points. You can see the effect with `a \hfill b \hfill` and `a \hfill b \hfill\null`. Herbert's answer in the linked question describes precisely what `\null` is for.

Comment: You should try and look in the LaTeX manual for `\null`. You won't find it. This means that it is not a user level command. In the LaTeX kernel it is used in the definition of `\verb`, `\textcommabelow` and of `\textcommaabove`; also in the some internal commands and a couple of macros imported from plain TeX.

Comment: Hello @egreg, can you post the link where I can study it please?