# Use of \null versus \hbox{} in a table made with the longtable package

Tags: macros, horizontal-alignment

[In this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24919/what-is-null-and-when-do-we-need-to-use-it), `\null` is said to be equivalent to `\hbox{}` and is therefore never needed. The same advice is more or less given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446165/using-of-null-command-alone) as it's not a user-level macro, which I take to be the same as "don't use it after `\begin{document}`".

I'm compiling a special calendar (using `longtable`), where some cells need to be empty. There's simply no entry for them. The original code which I'm borrowing uses `\null` for the blanks, but I'm wondering if that should be replaced by `\hbox{}` or if it would instead have any deleterious effects.

Here's an MWE stripped down to the bare bones. I don't know slash don't understand what's going on under the hood so to speak, but at least a Ctrl + F search-and-replace would be a trivial fix. Thanks for your insights.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow,makecell}

\begin{document}

\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\fontsize{8}{9}\selectfont

\begin{longtable}{>{\centering}p{0.025\textwidth}|>{\raggedright}p{0.040\textwidth}|>{\raggedleft}p{0.025\textwidth}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.85\textwidth}}
text & text & text & text \\ %% this looks ugly, it's fine for sample purposes.
\null & \null & \null & text \\ %% this generates empty space as needed.
\hbox{} & \hbox{} & \hbox{} & text %% it appears the same as the above line.

\end{longtable}

\normalsize

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use neither `\null` nor `\hbox{}`. Nothing is as good.

Comment: Or, nothing is as good as nothing ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `\null` is the same as `\hbox{}`, there can be no difference.

But there's no difference also if you type in nothing at all, which is actually the preferred way.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 

\usepackage{longtable,array}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt plus 1fil}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\fontsize{8}{9}\selectfont

\begin{longtable}{
  >{\centering}p{0.025\textwidth}|
  >{\raggedright}p{0.040\textwidth}|
  >{\raggedleft}p{0.025\textwidth}|
  >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.7\textwidth}
}
T & T & T & T \\ %% this looks ugly, it's fine for sample purposes.
\null & \null & \null & T \\ %% this generates empty space as needed.
\hbox{} & \hbox{} & \hbox{} & T \\ %% it appears the same as the above line.
T & T & T & T \\ %% this looks ugly, it's fine for sample purposes.
 &  &  & T \\ %% this generates empty space as needed.
 &  &  & T \\%% it appears the same as the above line.
 &  &  & \\ %% this generates empty space as needed.
 &  &  & T \\%% it appears the same as the above line.
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OK. So if `\null` is to be avoided, is `\hbox{}` in the same category? Or does it have legitimate (necessary even) usages? In any case, I'll go ahead and remove the extra "fluff."

Comment: @DomMocquereau `\null` is the same as `\hbox{}`

Comment: Right… I got that part. But my question is about the other way around. The previous answers say "don't use `\null`" and are silent about `\hbox{}` other than the answer to my own question where neither are needed (and since I've encountered it, I'd like to know if it should be avoided too…)